# Wikidata - Filter or Detect or Get incomplete date

Tags: wikidata, sparql

I've the following query

```
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?dod ?dob WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P570 ?dod.
  ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q5.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "es,en,it,fr,de,cs,[AUTO_LANGUAGE]". }
  OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P569 ?dob. }
    FILTER(?dod < (NOW()))
FILTER (?item IN (wd:Q4173012))
}
ORDER BY DESC(?modified) DESC(?dod) ?item
```

that in the example provided (`Q4173012`) returns four multiple values because has date with incomplete data, for example "`2019`" for date of death, that returns 2019-01-01. I need to filter these cases, I could do it if only get the 2019 so I can know that is an incomplete data, in order to not confuse those records that actually born or death on `01-01`

There is some way to convert this query to get the specific data as is shown in wikidata or filter this behavior? Because for incomplete data in wikidata is shown good:

[image]

I hope I can be clear, my english is not so good. Thanks in advance and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Data model](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format#Data_model)
- [Time](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format#Time)

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?dob ?precision_int ?precision_word WHERE {
  VALUES (?precision_int ?precision_word) { (6 "millenia") (7 "century") (8 "decade")
                                            (9 "year")     (10 "month")  (11 "day")
                                            (12 "hour")    (13 "minute") (14 "second") }

  ?item p:P569 [ a wikibase:BestRank ;
                 psv:P569 [ wikibase:timeValue ?dob;
                            wikibase:timePrecision ?precision_int ] ]

# FILTER NOT EXISTS {
#   ?item p:P569 [ a wikibase:BestRank ;
#                  psv:P569 [ wikibase:timeValue ?dob_;
#                             wikibase:timePrecision ?precision_int_ ] ]
#   FILTER (?precision_int < ?precision_int_)
# }

  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "es,[AUTO_LANGUAGE]". }

} VALUES (?item) {(wd:Q4173012)}
```

[Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3Fdob%20%3Fprecision_int%20%3Fprecision_word%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20VALUES%20%28%3Fprecision_int%20%3Fprecision_word%29%20%7B%20%286%20%22millenia%22%29%20%287%20%22century%22%29%20%288%20%22decade%22%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%289%20%22year%22%29%20%20%20%20%20%2810%20%22month%22%29%20%20%2811%20%22day%22%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2812%20%22hour%22%29%20%20%20%20%2813%20%22minute%22%29%20%2814%20%22second%22%29%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20p%3AP569%20%5B%20a%20wikibase%3ABestRank%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20psv%3AP569%20%5B%20wikibase%3AtimeValue%20%3Fdob%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wikibase%3AtimePrecision%20%3Fprecision_int%20%5D%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%23%20FILTER%20NOT%20EXISTS%20%7B%0A%23%20%20%20%3Fitem%20p%3AP569%20%5B%20a%20wikibase%3ABestRank%20%3B%0A%23%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20psv%3AP569%20%5B%20wikibase%3AtimeValue%20%3Fdob_%3B%0A%23%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wikibase%3AtimePrecision%20%3Fprecision_int_%20%5D%20%5D%0A%23%20%20%20FILTER%20%28%3Fprecision_int%20%3C%20%3Fprecision_int_%29%0A%23%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22es%2C%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%22%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%7D%20VALUES%20%28%3Fitem%29%20%7B%28wd%3AQ4173012%29%7D)

Comment: thanks! I have to study this! :D Nice work, as always!

Comment: nice! this works perfect for filter pourposes. Thanks a lot.